# Unresolved reference: kotlinx (Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx

Unresolved reference: kotlinx.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the plugin part of `build.gradle` (Project Level) as well as Module Level?

Comment: Yes, review my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**In your project-level build.gradle(Module)**

```
plugins {    id'com.android.application'    id'kotlin-android'    id'kotlin-android-extensions'}
```

Build.gradle(Module)

[image]

Section --> Plugins{}
[image]